# Sqlite3 Display Number of Rows

Tags: sqlite

In MySQL when I make a selection there is a summary telling me how many rows were selected

```
mysql> select * from frank;
+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| id                                         | numeric_id |
+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| home::sdfsdf                               |          2 |
| home::asfd                                 |          1 |
| home::asdf                                 |          6 |
| local::/home/sdf                           |          5 |
+--------------------------------------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)  <-- See! See! Here it is!
```

In SQLite3's command line utility, there is no such summary.

```
sqlite> select * from frank;
id|numeric_id
home::sdfsdf|2|
home::asfd|1|
home::asdf|6|
local::/home/sdf|5|
```

This makes me sad, because I would like to know how many rows are in my selection.

I know using `.header` turns on the column headers, is there a `.summary` equivalent of some sort as well?

Comment: `select count(*) from (MY_QUERY)`

Answer (score 0):

The `sqlite3` shell has no such function.